# Usage of DotNetZip

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I am using DotNetZip library to compress files. my code is given below

```
String[] filenames = { "D:\\Data\\ReadMe.txt", "c:\\data\\collection.csv","c:\\ProgramFiles\\reports AnnualSummary.pdf"};
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
   zip.AddFiles(filenames, "files");
   zip.Save("Archive.zip");
}
```

Now when the Archive.zip is created, there are folders created in the archive with the same name(e.g Data, ProgramFiles etc)for files in which they were stored.

My target is to compress all the files in Archive.zip without any folder in the archive. how can I achieve it?

Comment: maybe try using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx if you are on .net 4.5+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AddFiles has an overload to flatten the directory structure in the zip archive

```
public void AddFiles(
    IEnumerable<string> fileNames,
    bool preserveDirHierarchy,
    string directoryPathInArchive
)
```

http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/c64e89d3-2f1f-2886-16bc-291746b46718.htm

```
zip.AddFiles(filenames, false, "files");
```

The second parameter preserveDirHierarchy can be passed as false to have all files in the root of the zip archive. Be careful that you do not have files with the same name when doing this. It will throw an Exception for duplicate file names.